# Using jQuery and Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

So I need to provide a library for my client that displays a map, but I want to write this library using Mootools but the client has jQuery on his website. So my question is how will this affect the client website and what is the best way to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: if the client has jquery anyway, why not just go with that?

Comment: Because in the future I will sell this library to other clients that will use Mootools or other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

but keep in mind that you will no longer be able to use the dollar sign for jQuery. Instead you'll always have to write jQuery("selector")... etc.

see also: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
    $(function() {
        // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
    });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Comment: I need something something like this:

`
// jQuery to work with $ here

(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
// my code here
})

// jQuery to work with $ here`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Yes but this will take the $ from jQuery and all the code executed after my library will not work.